# Capistrano and several SSH keys

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano

I need Capistrano to use 2 different SSH keys. One is for the git repository, one is for the server to deploy to.

Whichever key I rename to id_rsa in my .ssh folder, works. The other one doesn't. If I rename the git key to id_rsa, Capistrano can connect to the git repository, but then can't authenticate at the server to deploy. If I call it something else, it will not be able to connect to the git repo. I know that the other key works, cause I can do ssh -i ~/.ssh/otherKey.pem and it will successfully connect to the server.

This is what I have in my deploy.rb Capistrano file.

```
ssh_options[:keys] = [
        File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "id_rsa"),
        File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "deploy")
    ]

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

How can I tell Capistrano to use BOTH the keys? It only seems to use the one called id_rsa.

edit:

Here's the output from Capistrano with the error message:

```
$ cap yii deploy
  * executing `yii'
Yii
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@project.beanstalkapp.com:/projectyii.git HEAD"
  * executing "git clone -q git@project.beanstalkapp.com:/projectyii.git /var/www/projectyii-trunk/releases/20110824174629 && cd /var/www/projectyii-trunk/releases/20110824174629 && git checkout -q -b deploy 5e14521285ca04a605353e97bdf31c3a2889dbfb && (echo 5e14521285ca04a605353e97bdf31c3a2889dbfb > /var/www/projectyii-trunk/releases/20110824174629/REVISION)"
    servers: ["yii.project.com"]
    [yii.project.com] executing command
 ** [yii.project.com :: err] Error reading response length from authentication socket.
 ** [yii.project.com :: err] Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
 ** [yii.project.com :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/projectyii-trunk/releases/20110824174629; true"
    servers: ["yii.project.com"]
    [yii.project.com] executing command
    command finished
failed: "sh -c \"git clone -q git@project.beanstalkapp.com:/projectyii.git /var/www/projectyii-trunk/releases/20110824174629 && cd /var/www/projectyii-trunk/releases/20110824174629 && git checkout -q -b deploy 5e14521285ca04a605353e97bdf31c3a2889dbfb && (echo 5e14521285ca04a605353e97bdf31c3a2889dbfb > /var/www/projectyii-trunk/releases/20110824174629/REVISION)\"" on yii.project.com
```

edit:

Another thing: it totally works fine from my local machine, just not on the deploy server - with exactly the same config files! It seems Capistrano uses the correct keys on my local machine, but not on the deploy machine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this problem out?  I'm having the same one.

Answer (score 29):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about Capistrano.

If it simply does normal `ssh` calls (or calls `git` to do this), you can configure the right key to use in your `~/.ssh/config` on a per-host (or per-host-alias) basis.

For example, I have these lines in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
# Git bei Github
Host github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/svn_id_rsa

#  Andere Mathe-Hosts
Host *.math.hu-berlin.de
User ebermann
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ControlMaster auto
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the idea. I set it up to that 'ssh deploy.server.com' connects into the deploy server directly. But still, Capistrano fails at authenticating itself to deploy.server.com - it's literally the same URL. :-( Any other ideas?

Comment: Could it be that Capistrano somehow sets the wrong username? A username given to SSH on the command line overrides the one in the config file. Other than this, showing the error message (if any), and maybe any debug output might help.

Comment: That could be possible, which username would that be/how do I test it? I set the username with set :user, it should be right. But even when I comment that out, it doesn't work. I added the entire Cap output to the original question.

Answer (score 11):

I have this line in deploy.rb:

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/Users/victor.pudeyev/ec2/MBP-2.pem)
```

This suggests that the key filenames are space separated, e.g.

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/Users/victor.pudeyev/ec2/MBP-1.pem /Users/victor.pudeyev/ec2/MBP-2.pem)
```

Comment: %w(...)  creates an array of strings with from space separated tokens, so this can't be the issue

Comment: undefined local variable or method `ssh_options' , maybe this has been changed in newer version

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and had ssh forwarding set in the capfile.  Removing that, allowed the target box to use its own keys

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party here, but one option is to use a bit of ruby glue to detect which file to use:

```
['~/.ssh/onekey.pem','~/.ssh/id_rsa'].each do |name|
  if File.exists?(File.expand_path(name))
    ssh_options[:keys] ||= name
  end
end
```