# Capistrano deploying to different servers with different authentication methods

Tags: amazon-ec2, capistrano

I need to deploy to 2 different server and these 2 servers have different authentication methods (one is my university's server and the other is an amazon web server AWS)

I already have running capistrano for my university's server, but I don't know how to add the deployment to AWS since for this one I need to add ssh options for example to user the .pem file, like this:

```
ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "test.pem")] 
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

I have browsed starckoverflow and no post mention about how to deal with different authentication methods [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633758/deploying-a-rails-app-to-multiple-servers-using-capistrano-best-practices) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661868/using-capistrano-to-deploy-a-rails-application-to-multiple-web-servers)

I [found a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154161/capistrano-and-several-ssh-keys) that talks about 2 different keys, but this one refers to a server and a git, both usings different pem files. This is not the case.

I got to [this tutorial](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html), but couldn't find what I need.

I don't know if this is relevant for what I am asking: I am working on a rails app with ruby 1.9.2p290 and rails 3.0.10 and I am using an svn repository

Please any help os welcome. Thanks a lot

Comment: You may find a more suitable audience on serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll post the question there aswell

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capistrano multi-stage. There is a gem that does this or you could just include an environments or stage file directly into the capfile.

You will not be able to deploy to these environments at the same time, but you could sequentially.

```
desc "deploy to dev environment"
 task :dev do
 set :stage_name, "dev"
 set :user, "dev"
 set :deploy_to, "/usr/applications/dev"
 role :app, "10.1.1.1"
end

desc "deploy to aws environment"
 task :aws do
  set :stage_name, "aws"
  set :user, "aws"
  set :deploy_to, "/usr/applications/aws" 
  ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "test.pem")] 
  ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
  role :app, "10.2.2.2"
 end
```

You would run:

```
cap dev deploy; cap aws deploy
```

You can expand this complexity to open VPNS, users, gateways, etc.