# Deploy to a different server using capifony

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capifony

I'm using Symfony 2.3.4 and Capifony

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113520/capistrano-deploying-to-different-servers-with-different-authentication-methods) but it doesn't work for me.

Anybody knows or has implemented something similar?

Comment: Until you tell us more details we won't be telling you anything. :) Google yourself or show your configs. First is preferred ofc.